# How to write Parameters into text file that passed from command line in power shell?

Tags: powershell

How to write Parameters into text file which are passed from command line

```
Param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[ValidateNotNull()]
[int]$Var1,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[ValidateNotNull()]
[int]$Var2
)
$Var1> 'C:\output.txt'
$Var1 | Set-Content 'C:\output.txt'



CommandLine:Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  Parameters.ps1 -Var1 1 -Var2 2
```

I want to Print these Parameters passed form command line into a text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($key in $MyInvocation.BoundParameters.keys)
{
    $value = (get-variable $key).Value 
    "$key -> $value" | Out-File -Append params.txt
}
```